# Visual Studio local DB server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have just downloaded VS Community 2015, and I am having great problems to create a local database on web application project or form application. Every time I am trying to create a Local server (Server based file in app data) I have a pop up that says ""Network related" or "instance specific" the server was never found orwas accessible.Verify that the server name is correct and SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."
The full message is display below
Can someone help me this please?

enter image description here

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed & running?

Comment: Search this site for the exact error message you're seeing. This question has been asked (and answered) many times before.

Comment: @SLaks I dhisto not have SQL server running, is this a problem? I thought  I could just create a local DB file without having anything?